# When an Angular directive creates elements, is it necessary to remove those elements in ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular

When an  Angular directive creates elements using renderer2, is it necessary to remove those elements when the directive / host is destroyed.

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
...
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,private hostElement: ElementRef){}
...
    const ele = this.hostElement.nativeElement;
    const span = this.renderer.createElement('span');
    this.renderer.appendChild(ele, span);
...
```

Because I am using renderer2 does angular handle all of this under the hood without my intervention or should I add a reference to the element and destroy it manually:

```js
...
mySpan: HTMLElement;
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,private hostElement: ElementRef){}
...
    const ele = this.hostElement.nativeElement;
    this.mySpan = this.renderer.createElement('span');
    this.renderer.appendChild(ele, span);
...
//is this required?
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.mySpan){
        this.renderer.removeChild(this.hostElement.nativeElement, this.mySpan);
    }
  }
```

Comment: No you dont need remove, Angular will handle it when the component gets destroyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Indraraj26 mentions, it's not necessary to remove children created from attribute directives. Your host-component will take care of that.

What you **will** need to take care of in the `ngOnDestroy`-method would be (when applicable):

- Removing listeners from the DOM
- Unsubscribing from Observables

(there's probably a few more cases, that I can't come up with right now)

Comment: I'm on the right track, thank you for your confirmation. I saw this done in someone's code. I was sure it was unnecessary but I could not shake that "but what if YOU are the one who has been doing it wrong” feeling.